# IOS devices issues with HTML form input (type = text)

Tags: html, ios, iphone, forms, input

So I have an HTML login form with two fields: Email and Password. These can be filled easily on any device's browser other than IOS devices(iPhone,iPad).
On IOS fields can hardly be in focus and once in focus,the keyboard pops up, I start typing but nothing is actually being filled. I have tried in both Chrome and safari and still get the same result. Field remains blank. Below is how my form is formatted:

```
<form method="post" name="login" action="login">
   <div class="divInputWrapper ">
      <i class="icon-envelope inputIcon inlineElt"></i>
      <label for="email"></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" class="formInput"/>
   </div>
   <div class="divInputWrapper ">
      <i class="icon-envelope inputIcon inlineElt"></i>
      <label for="password"></label>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="formInput"/>
    </div>
    <button class="blue centeredContent">Login</button>
</form>
```

I tried adding an autofocus attribute, preset a value and still the same.

Comment: Do you have any external css/js running?

Comment: Does your formInput class have any odd styles in it? like setting the color and the background-color to the same value? e.g. There isn't anything technically wrong in the code sample... so it should work.

Comment: I don't think we can't insert text into a textbox in ios devises. Guys at apple are not that stupid. There are many projects having forms where people can enter text in ios devices. It's obvious that the issue is  something specific to your project. such as js, css etc which you haven't provided.

Comment: Side note: your `<label>` tags are not going to be effective as the `for` attribute will only match on an `id` attribute on the form elements they are associated with. (and you don't have any ids specified)

Comment: @scunliffe thanks for the hint about label. I  used to think it was link via the name attribute. However the problem was not related to any JS file but a styling issue as u suggested. it was all because of some **stylesheet reset** I used. I will post the **answer bellow**. Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 82):

Found the issue, it's a stylesheet reset I found online to help with touch devices behaviour for when the user touch/ hold an element and I copied it across most of my projects. So if you have this issue, it's most likely you have these lines in your css:

```
  *, *:before, *:after {
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
     }
```

So just remove it or set it to default. And if your intention is to stop people from selecting stuff on your website, then make sure you reset this style property to default on **inputs**

```
  input, input:before, input:after {
      -webkit-user-select: initial;
      -khtml-user-select: initial;
      -moz-user-select: initial;
      -ms-user-select: initial;
      user-select: initial;
     }
```

Comment: Excellent, I searched long and hard for this one, I was debugging & utterly bemused. Thanks for this. I actually ended up with these styles from an import I did from the bootstrap less files, but I have the base styles the same for my inputs and buttons, so the CSS for aiding with buttons simultaneously got applied to my inputs..

Comment: I'm having the same issue and the solution above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh thank you. It is really hard to debug it. I thought it was on javascript part because I am using angular. The input can only accept one character and it seems lost focus while it's actually doesn't.

Comment: I can't believe it. How did you find this out? Funny enough, it works on everywhere else but iOS.

Comment: You cannot use :before and :after with input elements

Comment: you saved me - thank you so much, always something with ios... getting really really tired of it

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but its cause was very specific. I hope someone will still find it useful.

I use [webp-hero](https://github.com/chase-moskal/webp-hero) polyfill for `.webp` images support in Safari and it turns out, it's causing this problem on iOS devices. This is a [known bug](https://github.com/chase-moskal/webp-hero/issues/18) on their side, but I struggled forever to connect the dots.

Unfortunately, I don't have a good solution for this. For now, I avoid using .webp images on pages with forms.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening because of your unsupported font. If you want the input field or password to be supported on Mac os (Chrome or Safari)

use

```css
line-height:24px;
font-family: sans-serif;
display:block;
```

Check This fix and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was with the angular-material package, version 1.1.2.  After the update (1.1.18), everything works as expected.