# ios device input type ="text" value is not displaying as we enter the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, wordpress

Greetings for the Day!!!!

I am using  **WordPress contact form 7** with input type = "text". If I open the form in ios device I am not able to see the value which I typed.

I tried using this solution,
[IOS devices issues with HTML form input (type = text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610517/ios-devices-issues-with-html-form-input-type-text)
but no use.

if I alert the value on keyup the value is getting alerted.

Please help me in resolving it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check the background color of input field and color of text you entered in the text field

Answer (score 0):

I think the its with css problem.

Try

```
body{
  position:fixed !important
}
```

in IOS the html input type lose the focus when the keypad pops up. Its displaying the content somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

@Prasobh E

no, it dint worked out.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to background color and color overlapping

check the background color of input field and color of text you entered in the text field

if the background color and color matches, then absolutely text wont be visible

lets take `background-color: #555;` and color is `color:#555`